# pygame image AttributeError

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a pacman game with pygame but I have run into a few problems. It it saying that the 'Food' has no image.

This is my pacman game [code redacted].

The problem is this area here something is wrong and it tells me that food has no attribute image

```
class Food(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,color):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        pygame.image = pygame.Surface([7,7])
        self.image.fill(color)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.top = y
        self.rect.left = x
    def update (self,player):
        collidePlayer = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,player,False)
        if collidePlayer:
            food.remove
```

Comment: I don't see the error posted anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing all the irrelevant bits, do you see the difference between the following Sprite subclasses' `__init__` methods?

```
class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite): 

    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height, color):#For when the walls are set up later
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height]) # <-------------
        self.image.fill(color)

class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__ (self,x,y):

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([13,13])  # <-------------
        self.image.fill(white) 

class Food(pygame.sprite.Sprite)
    def __init__(self,x,y,color):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        pygame.image = pygame.Surface([7,7])  # <----- this one is different!
        self.image.fill(color)
```

The reason you're getting an error saying that `self` doesn't have an `image` attribute is because you didn't set `self.image`, you stored the image in the `pygame` module itself.

PS: The lines which look like

```
        food.remove
```

seem suspicious to me.  If `remove` is a method, it'd be called by `food.remove()`, and `food.remove` wouldn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks I will try that out. Yeah I'm pretty sure it should be food.remove() but I haven't had the time to go over and check that but thanks a heap for that